# Wolfram API Cross Origin Issue

Tags: javascript, xml, api, wolfram-mathematica

I've been trying to work with the Wolfram API but I've come across the cross origin issue every time I make an xhtml request. After some research, I've figured that the best way to overcome this is by using JSONP. I have the following code, but it doesn't work as I believe Wolfram is confusing the callback function with the AppID (which I've hidden and put xxx instead, o/w works perfectly fine):

```
<script>
function processJSON (json) {
  // Process the JSON response
};

// Create a new script element
var script_element = document.createElement('script');

// Set its source to the JSONP API
script_element.src = 'http://api.wolframalpha.com/v2/query?input=pi&appid=xxx?jsoncallback=processJSON&format=xml?';

// Stick the script element in the page <head>
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script_element);
```

The reason I know Wolfram is confusing the AppID is through using the web console on Firefox, as it says the appId is not valid.

I've been stuck on this for a while now, so any help would be appreciated; thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `?` character **starts** a query string. key=value pairs within a query string are separated with `&` characters.

That said, Wolfram Alpha's API does not appear to support JSON, JSONP or being called from a browser.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Is there no way to use JSONP for this? If not, do you know of any other way or bypass the cross origin issue for Wolfram?

Comment: Make the request from your server.

Comment: I see. But how can we be sure Wolfram doesn't support JSONP? (aside from my failure to do so for some time :S :P)

Comment: @user3651766 — We can't be *sure* that they don't, but since their documentation doesn't say that they do…